# SQLite - Tricky query for max(column)

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

I have built a schema with SQL Fiddle:

[SQL Fiddle - Schema](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/2f30a/6)

We have these columns in the ***testtable***:

1. **id** [int] as primary key (*not used -> not important*)
2. **end** [int] - if a new stream is written into the table all but the last time have value '0' and the last one has the value '1'. This is to refer that the input-stream is finished here.
3. **time_abs** [int] - an absolute time (e.g. in minute-steps).
4. **r_m** [double] - is the mass rate sumed up over the time
5. **T_r** [double] - does not matter
6. **type** [string] - also does not matter here
7. **x0** [string] - departure (e.g. where does the water come from?)
8. **x1** [string] - destination (e.g. where does the water flow in?)

As you can see in the SQL Fiddle Schema we query every mass at a certain location and at a certain  time like this:

```
SELECT
(SELECT (SELECT total(r_m) 
         FROM testtable 
         WHERE time_abs=11 AND end=0 AND x1='vessel2') + 
        (SELECT total(r_m) 
         FROM testtable 
         WHERE end=1 AND time_abs <=11 AND x1='vessel2')
)
-
(SELECT (SELECT total(r_m) 
         FROM testtable 
         WHERE time_abs=11 AND end=0 AND x0='vessel2') + 
        (SELECT total(r_m) 
         FROM testtable 
          WHERE end=1 AND time_abs <=11 AND x0='vessel2')
)
```

Which works well and fast.

But what we now want to query is the **maximum** of **r_m** at a certain **time range**.

E.g. ***pseudo code***:

```
SELECT max(total(r_m)) 
WHERE time_abs BETWEEN 1 AND 30 & SELECT time_abs WHERE r_m=max ...
```

So that the result of this pseudo query is (123, 13-24) (***max(total mass)***, ***time span where total mass=max***) (manually checked at the SQL Fiddle Schema).

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you summing only the stream ends (`end = 1`) of the old inflow?

Comment: Because the inflow streams are incremented untill finished. So `end=1` is the total mass of the old inflow. We only need this value as it contains all the information of the same flow where `end=0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a query that shows the level in vessel 2 between 5 and 26 seconds:

```
select  times.time_abs
,       sum(
        case when x1 = 'vessel2' and ([end] = 1 or times.time_abs = tt.time_abs)
             then r_m else 0 end - 
        case when x0 = 'vessel2' and ([end] = 1 or times.time_abs = tt.time_abs) 
             then r_m else 0 end
        ) as lvl
from    (
        select  distinct time_abs
        from    testtable
        where   time_abs between 5 and 26
        ) times
join    testtable tt
on      tt.time_abs <= times.time_abs 
        and 'vessel2' in (tt.x0, tt.x1)
group by
        times.time_abs
```

To just display the maximum, you can:

```
select  max(lvl) 
from    (
        ...query from above...
        ) as SubQueryAlias
```

[Live example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/2f30a/7/0)

Comment: It works! Ty! But it is pretty slow when I try it at a big table with ~20 million rows and a bigger time span. Is it possible to speed it up somehow??

Comment: Try various indexes, like `(time_abs, end, x0, x1, r_m)`, `(x0, time_abs, end, r_m)`, `(x1, time_abs, end, r_m)`, and `(end, time_abs, x0, x1, r_m)`?

Comment: I have tried this an for a time-span _1_ to _110_ it now takes 4 s, comapared to _260 s before. But if I increase the values to let's say _1_ to _1110_ it takes 400 s with indexes. Any other idea?? As we most likely want the maximum over one year which will be a time span of 525600 (in minutes) this definitly takes too long

Comment: Maybe there is another way to "batch"-Select over a certain time span? The initital select-statement (see question) is really fast with times <1ms for random query-time.

Comment: A faster approach is to iterate over the entire table while tracking the current level.  I can't think of a way to do that in SQLite, which does not support window functions or variables.  If I were you, I'd try a client language, like Python.

Comment: Ty again! Do you think we would gain a performance boost with python compared to Java-code? Also do speed things up I am think about combining multiple Select-statements, but all I can think of is `UNION ALL` which has a limit of (500?) Selects. Is there another way to do so?

Comment: Any client language should work.  I'd just iterate over the entire table using a single select, no union required.  A client program can track all levels and maximums in all vessels while iterating.

Comment: Btw I will accept your initial answer as it does what we want but only things are getting too slow at huge tables.